# Eclipse Quick Diff - when entering one addition it seems as if the entire file had changed

Tags: compare

I'm using eclipse quick diff and I would like to see only the changes I've made to the code.
So I selected reference source = Latest CVS Revision, green color for additions and I marked "show differences in overview ruler". 
Now - the problem is: When I enter ONE new line and save - the entire ruler gets painted in blue and green, probably due to the insert of this one line.
This is not what I need. I need it to show only the additions or updates I'm making to the code.

Answer (score 0):

So finally I got the reason - the auto formatting upon save. each time I saved the file it changed the lines order and that's the reason quick diff saw many changes and additions.
well... 
hope it'll help someone.. :)